# git branch history is not updating

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have two branches `development` and `master`, I merged a pull request from `development` to `master` successfully. I tried to verify the merge by creating a new PR from `development` to `master`, surpisingly I see the same commits and file differences again in new PR. But in real the changes have been merged successfully as I verified the changes manually in master branch.

Any idea what could be the reason for these false differences in PR and how could we fix it? I've tried already merging the master to development, but it's not helping.

Comment: Pull request is not a Git feature. Just `git fetch` and examine the tree directly.

Comment: Which merge strategy did you choose when you completed the PR of `development` to `master`? Also try this: in the new PR, if you select "View Merge Commit", do you see any changes?

Comment: @TTT: I did reverse integration. I don't see the "View Merge Commit" option, but there is "View Merge Changes" and under this I see there are about 15+ commit differences and NO file changes.

Comment: @John By "merge strategy", I was asking about the AzDev PR merge strategy. But based on your answer to my second question, I understand what happened. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr:** The reason it looks like the second PR is going to re-merge your changes again is due to the merge strategy you selected when you completed the first PR. For merging one long running branch into another, you should consider using the regular "Merge" strategy which will prevent this problem from happening again in the future.

**Details:**
In Azure DevOps (and most SCM tools), when you [complete a Pull Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=azure-devops#complete-the-pull-request) you can choose from various merge strategies. The 4 available strategies in AzDev are:

1. **Merge (no fast forward)**: Non-linear history preserving all commits.
2. **Squash commit**: Linear history with only a single commit on the target (squash merge your pull request).
3. **Rebase and fast-forward**: Rebase source commits onto target and fast-forward.
4. **Semi-linear merge**: Rebase source commits onto target and create a two-parent merge.

Only the first option, "Merge", will guaranteed that every commit ID from the source branch will show up in the target branch. What happened in your case, was that you selected either type 2, 3, or 4, and the commit IDs from `development` are not on `master`, *even though all of the code changes are.*

When you create a PR, AzDev displays all of the commits that exist on the source branch that are not in the target branch, and then uses the **merge-base** of the two branches to determine what files have changed from *the source branch's point of view*. If you want to see what files will actually be changed when you complete the PR, then you need to view the "merge commit" or "merge changes". In your case, your second PR is showing commits that were already merged (because their IDs aren't in `master`), but when you view the "merge changes" you see nothing, which is what you would expect since all of the code has already been merged.

To prevent this from happening in the future, I would recommend using merge strategy #1 (Merge with no fast forward) anytime you're merging `development` into `master` or vice versa. Note you can use other merge strategies when completing normal PR's. My personal favorite for merging feature/topic branches into long running branches such as `development` or `master` is type 4, Semi-linear merge.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Squash was used by default, I never noticed it. I changed it to type 1 and that fixed the problem :)